# Объединение несколько значений input в один.

Tags: input, javascript

Доброй день. Нудно объединить несколько значений input в один.
Например у меня есть

```
<input id="input1" name="input1"/>
<input id="input2" name="input2"/>
```

Мне нужно значение из input1 и input2 автоматически перенести в input3, причем нужно чтобы текст отображался последовательно т.е сначала input1 потом input2.

```
<input id="input3" name="input3"/>
```

Благодарю за любую помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/412cvgr4/1/)

```
input1.addEventListener('keyup', joinValues, false);
input2.addEventListener('keyup', joinValues, false);

function joinValues(){
    input3.value = input1.value + ' ' + input2.value;
}
```

P.S. Если старые браузеры учитывать не нужно, то событие лучше взять не "keyup", а  "input"

Comment: Спасибо, да использую вариант с input.